# load_file() producing null

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I'm trying to read the content of /etc/passwd from mysql using the following query: `select load_file("/etc/passwd");`
However, I always seem to get NULL as the output.

```
mysql> select load_file("/etc/passwd");
+--------------------------+
| load_file("/etc/passwd") |
+--------------------------+
| NULL                     |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there a reason for this? the permission for the passwd file is the default permission.

Comment: I think `--secure-file-priv=dir_name` is enabled.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-file-priv... `SELECT @@secure_file_priv` wil give the the path where files can be loaded from

Answer (score 0):

If the `SELECT` works for you, then it will work for a hacker.

Think twice about breaking through this security barrier.